# Rebooted Ubuntu 12.04 after installing Nvidia driver. Monitor now says 'Out of Range'

Tags: nvidia, 12.04

Just to let you know before reading this. I am a complete Ubuntu noob.

After installing Ubuntu 12.04 I installed the Nvidia driver. It asked to be rebooted, so I did so. Now when I power up my monitor says 'Out of Range'.

I can get the terminal using Ctrl+Alt+F1 while it says 'Out of Range'. I've logged in through the terminal and I've tried typing the xrandr command thing but it says 'Can't open display'.

Also, every so often in the terminal it says something like this...

```
[  ###.######] sd #:#:#:#: [sbd] Assuming drive cache: write through
[  ###.######] sd #:#:#:#: [sbd] Asking for cache data failed
```

^ Not sure if that has anything to do with it.

Anyway, I appreciate any help. Thanks!

Comment: Have you solved this problem? I"m experiencing the same issue with my MythTV setup connected to my Samsung HDTV.

Answer (score 1):

First possibility: Try do uninstall the Nvidia driver from the terminal, boot into your system without the drivers and then reinstall the driver from `jocke-gtk`.

Second:
http://www.nvidia.com/object/unix.html
1. Choose your architecture
2. Download the file
3. chmod +x nvidia_driver_file_which_you downloaded
4. exit X
5. su
6. ./nvidia_driver_file_which_you_downloaded